# Syntax highlighting for shell sessions?

Tags: bug, tags, markdown, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

Edit: I've opened [an issue for this](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/516) in the code-prettify project on GitHub.

---

The author of the question [Why does bash login shell break here-doc command string argument?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/410531/135943) noted in the comments that:

> As expected, the broken SE syntax colouring now indicates to inexperienced eyes that the '> ' prompts are part of typed strings and the warning messages further destroy any highlighting utility.

I turned off the syntax highlighting by adding the `<!-- language: lang-none -->` tag, as described in the relevant meta thread:

- [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/307622)

However, it got me to wondering: why *doesn't* Stack Exchange support proper shell *session* syntax highlighting?

Oddly enough, including the tag `<!-- language: shell_session -->` *does* turn on some sort of syntax highlighting, even though I don't see `shell_session` anywhere in the supported languages list in the above linked Meta thread.

However, the syntax highlighting isn't great—it looks more like *shell* syntax highlighting than *shell session* syntax highlighting.  As noted, it doesn't properly identify the default `PS2` prompt of `>` and highlights it as though it is part of the quoted string.

GitLab.com has `shell_session` syntax highlighting, as mentioned [in this mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gitlabhq/Q_JVl-FS_d0/sx8wX1hoDgAJ).  I checked and GitLab's highlighting *does* properly handle `PS2` detection, and even error message detection.

Since the `shell_session` tag isn't even *mentioned* in https://github.com/google/code-prettify (and so I'm not sure why it does anything at all here on Stack Exchange), how can I propose improvements to the Stack Exchange functionality of `shell_session` highlighting so it can improve to be more like GitLab's?

---

Here is what GitLab's syntax highlighting looks like:

[image]

And here is Stack Exchange's highlighting of the same block:

[image]

Comment: `<!-- language: shell_session -->` only seems to do something because it assumes you want syntax highlighting and as it can't find anything named *shell_session` it fallback to `lang-default` which is a [best effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327677) prettifier. If there is no supported highlighter in code-prettify you would have to start there. Submit a PR so they have it their release. Once that is done you can start thinking of having it added on SE. Keep in mind that the prettifier is not often pulled, so it might take more like 6 to 8 months instead of the default 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @rene, huh, I thought I had checked for that possibility by using a nonsense string in place of `shell_session` and observing that it didn't apply any fallback highlighting, but trying that again it seems I observed incorrectly the first time.  Anyway, thanks to that tip I've now [opened a feature request](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/516).